# Let $f(x+h)=f(x)+g(x)h+a(x,h)$, then show that $f$ is affine.

Tags: real-analysis

Suppose $f,g:\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, are function that obey $f(x+h)=f(x)+g(x)h+a(x,h)$ for all $x,h \in R$, with $|a(x,h)| \leq Ch^3$ for some constant $C$. Show that $f$ is affine.

My idea: Define a function $K:[a,b] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ where $K(x)=f(x)-\frac{f(b)-f(a)}{b-a}x$, I observed that $K(a)=K(b)$, and if I show that it is continuous and its maximum and minimum value is zero, then I get my desired result. I am stuck at continuity.

Anyone can please suggest me some direction of this proof?

Comment: $ Ch^3 $ is always positive ?

Comment: How do you get $ K(a)=K(b)$?

Answer (score 1):

For every $x$,
$$\lim_{h\to0}(g(x)h+a(x,h))=0$$
so that $f$ and thereby also $K$ is continous.